# How to cancel scheduled transition in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

Transition Code,

```
d3.select('chart').select('svg')
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(sampleData)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .each(function (d,i) 
           {
                d3.select(this)
                  .transition()
                  .delay(i*50)
                  .attr('cx', function(d) {return d.x;})
                  .attr('cy', function(d) {return d.y;})
                  .attr('r', 4);
           });
```

How can I stop/cancel the scheduled/delayed transactions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As pointed out in the other answer, all you need is to schedule a new transition. However, the whole thing is much easier than what you're doing in your code -- there's no need for the separate `.each()` function. To schedule the transitions initially, you can simply do

```
d3.select('chart').select('svg')
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(sampleData)
  .enter().append('circle')
  .transition()
  .delay(function(d, i) { return i*50; })
  .attr('cx', function(d) {return d.x;})
  .attr('cy', function(d) {return d.y;})
  .attr('r', 4);
```

The function to stop all transitions (scheduled and running) is simply

```
d3.selectAll("circle").transition();
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m39bo8y1/).

Answer (score 31):

The accepted answer does not work with the most recent version of d3. If you're using d3 v4, you should call [`.interrupt()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#selection_interrupt) on your selection.

Comment: I'm working with d3 v6 and your answer is still valid and helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Starting a new transition on the element stops any transition that is already running. You can pause/stop a d3 transition by setting a new transition with duration as 0.

```
function stopCircleTransitions(){
    if(startedApplyingTransitions)
       d3.select('chart').select('svg')
         .selectAll("circle")
         .each(function(d,i){
             d3.select(this)
               .transition()
               .duration(0);
         });
    }
}
```

If you would like to stop the transition if and only if it is started applying, you can try the code below.

```
 var startedApplyingTransitions = false;
 d3.select('chart').select('svg')
   .selectAll("circle")
   .data(sampleData)
   .enter()
   .append('circle')
   .each(function (d,i){
       d3.select(this)
           .transition()
           .delay(i*50)
           .attr('cx', function(d) {return d.x;})
           .attr('cy', function(d) {return d.y;})
           .attr('r', 4)
           .each("end", function(){ //this code will do the trick
               startedApplyingTransitions = true;
           });
   });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In this case because of delay, there are chances that when you execute your code, the animation is not started at all. It is just scheduled but not started. I tried the same, It does not work.

Comment: Updated the code to check whether transition has already started  applying its changes. Hope this helps.