# How to cancel running transitions in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

Hello fellow stackoverflowers,

I use the enter/update/exit pattern for my D3 visualization. How can I cancel all running transitions? In my case I'm slowly fading out rectangles. However, if the user clicks buttons I need the transition to be canceled. First the rectangles only are gone CODE-WISE, when the transition has ended (which won't allow me to properly execute the "enter()"-function, since the function assumes that certain elements are still there - which is only the case till the end of the transition). Second, users will face an entirely new scenario, in which old transitions shouldn't be carry over.

Is there a way to somehow cancel old transitions, when new user inputs occur? Or how do I avoid this problem?

Thank you,
-mike

Comment: Calling `d3.transition()` first thing in your `enter()` function should do this.

Comment: maybe try [`d3.timer.flush()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1410#issuecomment-21347123)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903355/how-to-cancel-scheduled-transition-in-d3