# How to stop d3 transitions completely after button click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm fairly new to d3 (I'm using v5) and was wondering how I could completely stop transitions from occurring on a button click. The code I'm working on is similar to the sample code here:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg");

var data = [[10,20,"a"],[20,40,"a"],[30,60,"b"],[40,80,"b"],[50,100,"a"]];

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx",function(d){return d[0];})
    .attr("cy",function(d){return d[1];})
    .attr("r",5)
    .attr("opacity",0);

var text = svg.append("text")
          .attr("x",150)
          .attr("y",20)
          .text("Starting text");


d3.select("#button")
    .on("click",sequence);

function sequence(){
    svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .filter(function(d){return d[2] === "a";})
    .transition("1")
    .duration(500)
    .attr("opacity",1)
    .transition("2")
    .delay(2000)
    .duration(500)
    .attr("opacity",0.5)
    .transition("3")
    .delay(3000)
    .duration(500)
    .attr("opacity",0);

text.transition("3")
    .text("Highlighting a")
    .transition("4")
    .delay(2000)
    .text("Adding in b")
    .transition("5")
    .delay(3000)
    .text("Goodbye");

 svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .filter(function(d){return d[2] === "b";})
    .transition("6")
    .delay(2000)
    .duration(500)
    .attr("opacity",1)
    .transition("7")
    .delay(3000)
    .duration(500)
    .attr("opacity",0);
}
```

with fiddle link, https://jsfiddle.net/matthewosborne71/1skd2vep/9/.

The problem is that I don't want users of the graphic I'm working on to be able to restart the transitions by clicking the Start! button part way through the transition run. This just causes overlap between the first run and new run. Is there a way to cancel any ongoing transitions in the svg?

Thanks for any help!

----Edit------

Thanks to the interrupt comment below I was able to figure it out. For those interested look at the transition documentation here, https://github.com/d3/d3-transition, and look for interrupt.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903355/how-to-cancel-scheduled-transition-in-d3 visit this question

Comment: The link in the comment above is not useful for you, because you're using D3 v5, where a simple `interrupt()` is enough. However, due to the structure of your function, you'll need to refactor it completely.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @GerardoFurtado I was able to figure it out with your help!